# IdentityServer4: Unable to obtain configuration from: '{servicename}.well-known/openid-configuration'. docker issue

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I have an `identityserver4` container (`identitymanagement:5003/localhost:5003`) 
and a mvc app (`website.com:5000/localhost:5000`).

Once both are running in docker and I try to go to `localhost:5000/home/login` (to be redirected to the `identityserver`) I get the error

> Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://identitymanagement:5003/.well-known/openid-configuration'.

Here is all my different code parts

**MVC: Login call**

```
public IActionResult Login()
{
   return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties
   {
       RedirectUri = "/Manage"
   });
}
```

**MVC: Startup.cs**

```
public static IServiceCollection AddCustomAuthentication(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {

        var callBackUrl = configuration.GetValue<string>("logoutCallbackUrl");

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddCookie(x=>x.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(2))
        .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
        {
            options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.Authority = "https://identitymanagement:5003";
            options.SignedOutRedirectUri = callBackUrl.ToString();
            options.ClientId =  "website";
            options.ClientSecret = "secret";
            options.ResponseType = "code id_token";
            options.SaveTokens = true;
            options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            options.Scope.Add("openid");
            options.Scope.Add("profile");


        });

        return services;
    }
}
```

**IdentityServer Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));


        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();


        services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
            .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
            .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
            .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
            .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>();

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {

            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseIdentityServer();
        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
    }

}
```

**Identityserver: Config.cs**

```
public class Config
{
    public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApiResources()
    {
        return new List<ApiResource>
        {
            new ApiResource("resourceApi", "API Application")
        };
    }

    // scopes define the resources in your system
    public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> GetIdentityResources()
    {
        return new List<IdentityResource>
        {
            new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
            new IdentityResources.Profile(),
            new IdentityResources.Email()
        };
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
    {
        return new List<Client>
        {


            // OpenID Connect implicit flow client (MVC)
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "website",
                ClientName = "Public Website",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Hybrid,
                RequireConsent = false,
                ClientSecrets =
                {
                    new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                },

                RedirectUris = { "https://kryptoevents.com:5000/signin-oidc" },
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "https://kryptoevents.com:5000/signout-callback-oidc" },
                AllowedScopes =
                {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,

                }
            }
        };
    }

}
```

**docker-compose.override.yml**

```
  identitymanagement:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
      - ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=44378
    ports:
      - "60807:80"
      - "5003:443"

  website.com:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
      - ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=44395
    ports:
      - "56530:80"
      - "5000:443"
```

**NOTE**
If i do not run the services in docker and just run them on IIS and instead of `options.Authority = "https://identitymanagement:5003"`; changing it to `"https://localhost:5003"` then everything works as expected.

It seems that there is an issue inside docker and not being able to resolve `identitymanagment`

I have also tried using the IP address of the container instead of the `identitymanagement` and I get the same error.

Do I need to do anything special when it comes to certificates when running inside docker?

Comment: Hi, i am also facing the same and exact issue when running MVC app along with identity 4, its been 2 weeks I am stuck in this error, if any body have some good and useful solution please share with me, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

maybe in your docker.Yml try to change

```
  identitymanagement:
environment:
  - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
  - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80;https://+:5003
  - ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=5003
ports:
  - "60807:80"
  - "5003:5003"

  website.com:
environment:
  - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
  - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80;https://+:5000
  - ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=5000
ports:
  - "56530:80"
  - "5000:5000"
```

Because in yours Identityserver Config.cs and MVC: Startup.cs you set up to these specifiques ports

Comment: Idk how to configure in the right way but I think is because yours ports redirections in the docker yml when you put the ports arguments. When one request is in the port 56530 he goes to 80, the same think occurrs 60807 > 80